# Testing a poll app using Django test client

Tags: python, django

I am trying to test a poll app using the Django test client. In this test I create a POST request that mocks a vote on the poll and then checks both the status_code of the response (to check that I have been redirected) and verifies the number of votes has increased. So from what I have read, my `tests.py` ended up looking like this:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.test import TestCase
from mysite.polls.models import Question, Choice

class PollTest(TestCase):

    def test_voting(self):
        client = Client()
        # Perform a vote on the poll by mocking a POST request.
        response = client.post('/polls/1/vote/', {'choice': '1',})
        # In the vote view we redirect the user, so check the
        # response status code is 302.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        # Get the choice and check there is now one vote.
        choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(choice.votes, 1)
```

and the vote part of `views.py` looks like this:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args (question.id,)))
```

and my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
   ]
```

The first issue that I had, after running `python manage.py test` was that I had to change the response status code to 405, when it should be 302, because after choosing the vote and clicking on the vote button, I get redirected to `/polls/1/results`. Moreover, the vote is actually not being registered, as after changing the response status code, just to see whether atleast the vote has been increased, I get the error that 1 is wrong and it should be changed to 0, meaning that the voting process is also not functioning.

Comment: You shouldn't get 405 - that means 'Method not allowed'. My guess is that the wrong view is handling the request. Please show your `polls/urls.py`.

Comment: Note you don't need `client = Client()`. When using the Django `TestCase`, just use `self.client`.

Comment: I edited my post with `views.py`.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in the urls, not the views.

Comment: It looks like you are following a really old version of the tutorial - the model has been `Question` instead of `Poll` for a long time. That might not be the problem in this case, but you might hit other problems in future. Make sure you are using the latest Django release (currently 1.10 or 1.8 long term support), and follow the correct tutorial for that version

Comment: I totally misread and thought I had to add the `views.py`. I just added `urls.py` as well. I saw that there have been some changes to the tutorial, however, I do not think that that is causing the issue, but I may be wrong.

Comment: As you mentioned, the tutorial using poll_id was old and by mistake I added the wrong `views.py`. Now it should be ok.

Comment: I can't see anything in your current code to explain the 405 status code. You might have included `polls.urls` incorrectly. I would try adding `print('in vote view')` to the top of your `vote` view, to check that your test is actually calling that view.

Comment: I added the `print('ín vote view')` as suggested and I did get it in the test.

Comment: I changed that as well, as I mentioned, using the old tutorial I had to change some things and I did change everything according to what it should be, so the issue is not there.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, the view you have posted should not return a 405 response. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: I would also like to ask what is the idea behind `{'choice':1}` because I changed both 1 and choice and it did not seem to affect the test at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following decorator to allow POST:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def vote(request, poll_id):  # this is your method from above
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=question_id)
    try:
        ...
```

Otherwise, this view handles `GET` methods by default. At the same time, you really do want `vote()` to be restricted to `POST` calls because it is modifying your data.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods

In the test use `response = client.post(..., follow=True)` to follow redirects and test the end result.

Comment: I just did not understand, where should I add the decorator and what is really the purpose of it?

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `@require_http_methods(["POST"])`, but it doesn't explain the current problem.

Comment: Not registering `POST` can definitely be a reason for a 405 error and the missing entry in the database.